# Qt Creator : Read an image from resources

Tags: qt, opencv, resources, imread

I try to read image from resource.

Qt : 5.9.1 and OpenCV : 3.2

My code is :

```
// Set initial screen
QImage image;
cv::Mat src = cv::imread(":/images/initialScreen.png");
image = ImageFormat::Mat2QImage(src);
videoFrameLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
```

And my files :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bBLs.png)

My .pro file :

```
QT       += core gui
QT += widgets
QT += gui
CONFIG += c++14
QT += multimedia multimediawidgets
...

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp \
    imageformat.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h \
    imageformat.h \
    blob.h

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui

INCLUDEPATH += C:\opencv\build\include
LIBS += C:\opencv-build\bin\libopencv_video320.dll
...
LIBS += C:\opencv-build\bin\libopencv_imgcodecs320.dll


DISTFILES +=

RESOURCES += \
    rsc.qrc
```

It does not work, where do i make mistake? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only Qt classes that use [`QFile`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html) can read from resources stored using the Qt resource system, from the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html):

> The resource system is based on tight cooperation between qmake, rcc (Qt's resource compiler), and QFile.

Therefore, You have to read the data from the resource file using `QFile`, then supply the read data to [`cv::imdecode`](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga26a67788faa58ade337f8d28ba0eb19e) to get a `cv::Mat`.

Comment: oh! you are right, thank you so much!